# ExecutorService JVM doesn't terminate

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

I don't understand why I have to call `executorService.shutdown()` explicitly to terminate `executorService`. If I do not call `shutdown()` then the JVM does not terminate on its own.

What is wrong with my program or what concept am I missing?

```
public class ExecutorServiceExample {

    public static class Task1 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Message from Task1 :"
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

    }

    public static class Task2 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Message from Task2 :"
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

    }

    public static class Task3 implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Message from Task3 :"
                    + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        Future future1 = executorService.submit(new Task1());
        Future future2 = executorService.submit(new Task2());
        Future future3 = executorService.submit(new Task3());


    }

}
```

Output:

> Message from Task2 :pool-1-thread-2
>
> Message from Task1 :pool-1-thread-1
>
> Message from Task3 :pool-1-thread-3

The JVM is still alive. If I will call shutdown() then only JVM would die.

Comment: because that is the way it works why do you not want to follow the documentation?

Comment: Coz it wasn't mentioned in the documentation in a lucid manner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [`Thread` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html):

> The Java Virtual Machine continues to execute threads until either of the following occurs:
>
> - The exit method of class Runtime has been called and the security manager has permitted the exit operation to take place.
> - **All threads that are not daemon threads have died**, either by returning from the call to the run method or by throwing an exception that propagates beyond the run method.

Your executor creates non-daemon threads which prevent your JVM from shutting down. Threads created by executors are usually pooled to run more than one task submitted to the executor - often this is a performance optimisation to reuse threads so they run more then one task (as creating new thread is an expensive operation). Depending on the implementation and configuration of the executor (e.g. see [`ThreadPoolExecutor` doc, especially `keepalive` configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)) it might keep the threads running forever or terminate when they are unused for some time.

You must either call `shutdown` on your executor or create it with a custom [`ThreadFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadFactory.html) (e.g. using [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int, ThreadFactory)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory-)) where that thread factory will configure new threads as daemon ones.

Comment: But when these non-daemon threads complete the execution of run(), these non-daemon threads would die. But it is not happening in my case. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you use a ThreadFactory to create daemon threads, then those tasks that were submitted would not be executed completely when JVM exits. In the example of the question, this option would result in no message prints.

Comment: @JohnRambo Non-deamon executor's threads do not die after execution of Runnable is completed. They wait for another Runnable to be submitted to execute.

Comment: Daemon threads are essentially background processes. Don't create the Threads as daemons just because they have the "side effect" of not holding the VM hostage. Mark them as daemons if they actually ARE deamons. You are just making it more complicated because you now have to manually ensure that the VM doesn't shutdown before the work is completed. Calling `shutdown()` tells the `ExecutorService` to complete any outstanding work and to clean up Threads once they have completed their job, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: As an alternative, you might create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a minimum of 0 threads and a keepalive that is short enough to ensure the VM shuts down in time. For example: `ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 10, 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>())`. Now, if you submit work to the executor, it will run in a non-daemon Thread that is automatically cleaned up after a period of being idle. You don't have to call shutdown. The VM will wait for the Threads to complete, but it won't wait for it longer than the keepalive afterwards.