# Why doesn't a runBlocking block with a newSingleThreadExecutor end?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to figure out why this code i running infinitely:

```
fun main() = runBlocking {
launch {
    delay(200L)
    println("Task from runBlocking $coroutineContext")
}

//    coroutineScope { // if I uncomment this line and comment next line, then it will finish
CoroutineScope(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()).launch {
    launch {
        delay(500L)
        println("Task from nested launch $coroutineContext")
    }

    delay(100L)
    println("Task from coroutine scope $coroutineContext")
}

println("Coroutine scope is over")
}
```

When I run this code, I see this output:

```
Coroutine scope is over
Task from coroutine scope [StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@5287ba83, java.util.concurrent.Executors$FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService@91445f6]
Task from runBlocking [StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@28ac3dc3, BlockingEventLoop@32eebfca]
Task from nested launch [StandaloneCoroutine{Active}@702cf19c, java.util.concurrent.Executors$FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService@91445f6]
```

but the program never ends...
As I wrote in the comment, if I replace `newSingleThreadExecutor` line with just a simple `coroutineScope`, then it completes quickly.

Why isn't this code ending?

Comment: I think it's because a JVM executable won't exit until all non-daemon threads have exited. You've created a thread in your `newSingleThreadExecutor`. I'm not entirely sure what happens from there since you release control of it to `CouroutineScope` but I assume that keeps a reference to it. Try explicitly creating the thread pool before the call to `CoroutineScope` and then explicitly shutting it down after all the co-routines you've launched have finished.

Comment: from docs `Instances of [ExecutorCoroutineDispatcher] should be closed by the owner of the dispatcher.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is because non-daemon threads keep the JVM alive.

You need to shutdown your `ExecutorService` to properly let the JVM finish its execution.

This has been answered here:
[ExecutorService JVM doesn't terminate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999109/executorservice-jvm-doesnt-terminate)

Comment: then what is the suggested way to have/handle a single threaded coroutine scope?

Comment: `runBlocking` already runs in a single thread, otherwise you need to create and shutdown your own executor. This API exists in the coroutines library: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/new-single-thread-context.html but they will replace it later with something that doesn't require you to close the executor, and reuses threads from a shared pool I think

Comment: which means there is no neat way to do this, at least for now...